# Which HTML entities become ``forgotten'' (and replaced by UTF8 character) after putting them in an html element?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I work on Firefox under Windows 7. I want to replace all HTML entity `codes' (e.g. &copy;) from the content of a text form field by the UTF8 characters they correspond to (resp. ©) - and work on a text without HTML enity codes but having their UTF8 chars instead. So, my idea to do so is the following: put this content in an html element (say div), and finally read the content of this element. It turns out that most of HTML entities are replaced by UTF8 chars as I want, but this does not happen e.g. for: &lt;, &rt;, &amp; and &nbsp;. To be more precise, let me quote my original JS script and HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>

 <input type="text" id="user" onchange="convert()">
 <input type="text" id="my_test">
 <div id="for_tests"></div>

 <script>
 function convert()
 {
  var text = document.getElementById('user').value;
  document.getElementById('for_tests').innerHTML = text;
  var conv = document.getElementById('for_tests').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('my_test').value = conv;
 }
 </script>
 </body></html>
```

This short script works as follows: it reads the content of the first input (#user), then ``converts'' HTML entities and displays the result in the second input (#my_test). Surprisingly, if, for example, the content of #user input is:
&uuml; &lt; &gt; &amp; &nbsp; &copy; &ccedil; &#9917; < > & &#160;
then the content of #my_test input is:
ü &lt; &gt; &amp; &nbsp; © ç ⚽ &lt; &gt; &amp; &nbsp;
So, some HTML entities are converted and some other none. Can anyone explain what is the rule - that is, which HTML entities will be converted? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don’t feel like looking up where/whether this is specified, but if you want to fix it, read `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, and be aware that setting `innerHTML` can run scripts, so it’s not safe to do it on untrusted input. (A hacky, but correct… I think… way to fix that is to replace every `<` with `&lt;` first.)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I now about safety (and replacing < by suitable HTML entity). Here I only want to learn about the rule the browsers treat HTML entities. I checked my above example in other browsers (on Windows 7) and the result is perfectly the same. What is amazing is that entity #160 is replaced by nbsp.

Comment: Ry, thanks a lot for suggesting using textContent! If one replaces in my JS code the last innerHTML by textContent, it works perfect! I also learnt from the internet that innerHTML does not run scripts.

Comment: `innerHTML` *does* run scripts, just not `<script>`s. `<img src="foo" onerror="alert(1)">`. It also makes requests for images. Finally, valid tags aren’t included in `textContent`. The escaping hack is necessary on all levels.